# How to prevent Oracle from calling a function for every attribute of the function result

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've created a package, containing a function that returns an object.
When retrieving the object details through sql, the function is called multiple times - once for every detail retrieved.
*I believe it should be possible for it to just be called once instead.*

**Following is an example that demonstrates the issue:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_test AS OBJECT (
    v1              VARCHAR2(10),
    v2              VARCHAR2(10),
    v3              VARCHAR2(10),
    times_called    NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_pkg AS 
    times_called    NUMBER :=0;
    FUNCTION test(something IN VARCHAR2) RETURN t_test;
    PROCEDURE reset;

END test_pkg;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_pkg IS
    PROCEDURE reset IS
    BEGIN
        times_called := 0;
    END;
    
    FUNCTION test(something IN VARCHAR2) RETURN t_test IS
        
    BEGIN
        times_called := times_called + 1;
        RETURN t_test('first', 'second', 'third', times_called);
    END;

END test_pkg;
/
```

**Here we can see that the function is invoked four times:**

```
SQL> SELECT t.r.v1, t.r.v2, t.r.v3, t.r.times_called FROM (
  2      SELECT test_pkg.test('x') r FROM DUAL
  3  ) t;

R.V1       R.V2       R.V3       R.TIMES_CALLED
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------
first      second     third                   4

SQL>
```

**If we reset the counter, and only select two attributes, we can see it's called twice:**

```
SQL> exec test_pkg.reset();

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT t.r.v1, t.r.times_called FROM (
  2      SELECT test_pkg.test('x') r FROM DUAL
  3  ) t;

R.V1       R.TIMES_CALLED
---------- --------------
first                   2

SQL>
```

---

The actual stored procedure is more expensive, so I'd like to avoid re-calling it for every attribute listed.

The solution has to work on Oracle 10gr2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle is not materializing the sub-query and is pushing the function calls to the outer query. You need to force the SQL engine to materialize the inner query either by:

Using a seemingly unnecessary `ROWNUM > 0` filter:

```sql
SELECT t.r.v1, t.r.v2, t.r.v3, t.r.times_called
FROM (
  SELECT test_pkg.test('x') r
  FROM   DUAL
  WHERE  ROWNUM > 0
) t;
```

or, you should be able to use the ([undocumented](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=materalized-hint)) `/*+ materialize */` hint  but, for an unknown reason, it doesn't seem to want to materialize this particular query (although it does work for [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72230828/1509264)).

You can also (as [pointed out in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72662764/how-to-prevent-oracle-from-calling-a-function-for-every-attribute-of-the-functio/72662959?noredirect=1#comment128374006_72662959) by William Robertson) use the [`/*+ NO_MERGE */` hint](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm#26161) which "causes Oracle not to merge mergeable views":

```sql
SELECT t.r.v1, t.r.v2, t.r.v3, t.r.times_called
FROM   (
  SELECT /*+ no_merge */
         test_pkg.test('x') r
  FROM   DUAL
) t;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=71ec1d183ee3f0b933d9b97414b1d7ba)*

Comment: Brilliant! (Or perhaps inane on Oracle's part)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Which is why I said in the answer that `/*+ materialize */` does not work for this particular problem. It does work in the similar problem that I linked to.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my comment before I saw your reply. Yes, looking at your dbfiddle it seems the `materialize` hint is not honoured in this case (and 10g could not return object types from a `with` clause anyway, which is interesting from an ancient history perspective).

Comment: `no_merge` seems to do it. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c31765e8b6dca9b86a41f7d7961fc29c