Oracle query - strange explain plan behaviour when selecting from view
Having a problem with a long running query (Oracle 11g) .  Have narrowed the problem down to a view. This view is fairly complex and too detailed to list.
The problem is on running the select statement which is what the view (call it xyz_vw) is built on, I get explain plan 1.  However, if I do a select * from xyz_vw the explain is slightly different (and causing the problem) - explain plan 2. Doing select * from (select .....) also gives explain plan 1 where the select statement in brackets is the select statement of the view but not an option to use in the process.
Has anyone ever experienced the same problem - and know how to force explain plan 1 when referencing the view ?
Thanks
seamus
Tried forcing the explain that I wanted using hints - this worked for part of process when just selecting from view but later in the process, I need to update from the view and the hint causes the wrong explain plan to do this bit.   Dont think using hints is the answer and shouldn't really need to do this anyway.

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] that allows us to replicate the problem or, at the least, include the different EXPLAIN PLANs in question (but we probably also need the queries). Stating "This view is fairly complex and too detailed to list." is not constructive because if you don't give sufficient details to be able to know what the problem is then the question is too vague to be answerable.

If the solution is that you need to materialize the output of the view to prevent the SQL engine from rewriting the query and pushing joins and function calls to the outer query then this could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/72662764/1509264 (and solved by either using SELECT * FROM view_name WHERE ROWNUM > 0 or the NO_MERGE or (undocumented) materialize hints). However, without more details its impossible to tell what the solution should be.
