# Strange Oracle behavior

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to generate a uuid for each row in an existing table and set the same value for two different columns.

I wrote an update statement that I thought should do it, but it is setting a *different* uuid for each column. Why?

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    n number,
    r1 raw(32),
    r2 raw(32)
);

insert into tbl (n) values (1);
insert into tbl (n) values (2);
insert into tbl (n) values (3);

update (select r1, r2, sys_guid() as uuid FROM tbl) 
    set r1 = uuid, r2 = uuid;
    
select n, rawtohex(r1), rawtohex(r2) from tbl;
```

| N | RAWTOHEX(R1) | RAWTOHEX(R2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F89B6F66D7C7A52FE050020A02583951 | F89B6F66D7C8A52FE050020A02583951 |
| 2 | F89B6F66D7C9A52FE050020A02583951 | F89B6F66D7CAA52FE050020A02583951 |
| 3 | F89B6F66D7CBA52FE050020A02583951 | F89B6F66D7CCA52FE050020A02583951 |

Comment: I think you need to generate the guid once in a separate statement, then use it to do the update.  probably need to do this in pl/sql,

Comment: Looks like the same issue as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72230647/2778710.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72662764/1509264) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72230647/1509264) as the `SYS_GUID` function call is not being materialized in the sub-query and is being pushed to the update statement and called twice each row (once for each column); however, the answers to those questions don't quite work with an `UPDATE` statement.

Instead, you can use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO tbl d
USING (
  SELECT ROWID AS rid,
         SYS_GUID() AS uuid
  FROM   tbl s
) s
ON (s.rid = d.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET d.r1 = uuid,
      d.r2 = uuid;
```

Which, after the `MERGE`, your sample data may contain:

| N | RAWTOHEX(R1) | RAWTOHEX(R2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F89CAC01141C1982E053182BA8C018B2 | F89CAC01141C1982E053182BA8C018B2 |
| 2 | F89CAC01141D1982E053182BA8C018B2 | F89CAC01141D1982E053182BA8C018B2 |
| 3 | F89CAC01141E1982E053182BA8C018B2 | F89CAC01141E1982E053182BA8C018B2 |

---

An alternative is to use two `UPDATE` statements:

```sql
UPDATE tbl
SET r1 = SYS_GUID();

UPDATE tbl
SET r2 = r1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4-WkqJy9)

Answer (score 2):

As already said, this is because Oracle doesn't store calculated value but propagates the original expression to the outer query. While it doesn't do this in case of `join`.

To avoid joins during `merge` you may use `(column [, column ]...) = (subquery)` branch of `update`, generating as many the same calculated values as you need using `left join` to `dual`.

```
update tbl 
set (r1, r2) = (
  select a.uuid, a.uuid
  from dual
    left join (
      select sys_guid() as uuid
      from dual
    ) a
    on 1 = 1
  where tbl.r1 = tbl.r1
    or tbl.r1 is null
)
```

```
select n, rawtohex(r1), rawtohex(r2)
from tbl
where r1 = r2
```

| N | RAWTOHEX(R1) | RAWTOHEX(R2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F89DCA00DD9D1CE0E053182BA8C0E348 | F89DCA00DD9D1CE0E053182BA8C0E348 |
| 2 | F89DCA00DD9E1CE0E053182BA8C0E348 | F89DCA00DD9E1CE0E053182BA8C0E348 |
| 3 | F89DCA00DD9F1CE0E053182BA8C0E348 | F89DCA00DD9F1CE0E053182BA8C0E348 |

**UPD**.
There was an error in the above text because I've lost a correlation in the subquery to force per-row execution. So the code was updated.

You may also add `rownum` to the subquery in `set ... = (subquery)` instead of `join`.

```
update /*+gather_plan_statistics*/ tbl 
set (r1, r2) = (
  select a.uuid, a.uuid
  from (
      select sys_guid() as uuid
      from dual
      where rownum = 1
    ) a
  where tbl.r1 = tbl.r1
    or tbl.r1 is null
)
```

```
select n, rawtohex(r1), rawtohex(r2)
from tbl
where r1 = r2
```

| N | RAWTOHEX(R1) | RAWTOHEX(R2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F89DCA00DDA01CE0E053182BA8C0E348 | F89DCA00DDA01CE0E053182BA8C0E348 |
| 2 | F89DCA00DDA11CE0E053182BA8C0E348 | F89DCA00DDA11CE0E053182BA8C0E348 |
| 3 | F89DCA00DDA21CE0E053182BA8C0E348 | F89DCA00DDA21CE0E053182BA8C0E348 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WpFDqpXl)

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this query to work on the OP's data (when I rollback any prior updates before applying the next update) [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0BjcCIWk)

Comment: @MT0 Interesting point. Number of `starts` in actual plan is reduced to 1 after the rollback even if the query is different. But even if (sometimes) it is not, the result value is still the same